# How to find number of hit counts of a web page in web application in distributed environment

Tags: java, web

This question is specifically targeted for tracking number of hits of a web page when an application is deployed in distributed environment. 
I am aware that we can track number of hits either by using filter or interceptor (considering app has been built using spring framework) but I'm not able to figure out how can we track request if webApp is deployed in more than one application server.

Comment: By summing the hits of all the servers

Answer (score 1):

You can store hit counts in database. Database should be shared among the distributed web servers or you can use shared redis caches.